# Push Notification with firebase on react native application

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm currently trying to achieve push notification in my application built on react native. I'm able to receive notification sent from firebase console cloud messaging function but there are two problems I'm facing

1. When my application is in background, I'm able to receive
   notification only. Then when it is in foreground, I can't receive
   notification in my notification drawer.
2. When I'm clicking my notification it's containing nothing in it's notification field not text neither it's head or anything

   ```
    async componentDidMount() {
       await request_runtime_permission()
       await this.checkPermission();
       await this.createNotificationListeners();
     }
    async createNotificationListeners() {
       this.notificationListener = await firebase.notifications().onNotification((notification) => {
           console.log(notification);
           const { title, body } = notification;
           console.log(notificationOpen.notification)
           this.showAlert(title, body);
       });
      this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen) => {
           alert('onNotificationOpened')
           console.log(notificationOpen)
           const title = notificationOpen.title
           const body = notificationOpen.body
       });
     this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen) => {
           alert('onNotificationOpened')
           console.log(notificationOpen)
           const title = notificationOpen.title
           const body = notificationOpen.body
           console.log('title->', title, 'body->', body)
           this.showAlert(title, body);
       });
     const notificationOpen = await firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification();
       if (notificationOpen) {
           // alert('getInitialNotification')
           const { title, body } = notificationOpen.notification;
           console.log('title->', title, 'body->', body)
           this.showAlert(title, body);
       }}
   ```

I'm using following version

```
"react-native-firebase": "^5.1.1",
"react-native": "^0.55.4",
```

and following dependencies

```
 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
 "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4"
 "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1"
 "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1"
```

Comment: For receiving notifications in the foreground you have to rewrite your payload it should include both notification & data. Do JSON.stringify(notificationOpen) and check what are you getting in the object.

Comment: Yes. Check in your server side. Need notification & data in your pushnotification payload.
let payload = {
data: {
//your data
}, {
 title: title,
body: body
}
}

Comment: I have a question, I'm developing two apps first of the user app and second to providers, in user app, I made some function to send order and saved into real-time database firebase t and in the second app I just retrieve the data from DB with a listener to get the new order as a real-time without refreshing the app, SO I want to when I send an order from user app to firebase I want to display a notify in the second app? How to handle these